# Minkowski metric is negative?

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, physics, mathematical-physics

From what I understand about metrics, they have to be positive. However the Minkowski 'metric' can be negative for time-like separation of events. Is the Minkowski metric not actually a real metric?

Comment: It is a common clash of notation: the "metric" in metric spaces is not the same as in Riemannian manifolds and not the same on pseudo-Riemannian manifolds, such as Minkowski's space.

Comment: To add to Giuseppe's comment: the Minkowski metric doesn't even have the same "function signature" as the metric from a metric space: the Minkowski metric is a function in $\prod_{p \in M} (T_p M \times T_p M \to \mathbb{R})$ whereas the metric from a metric space is a function $M \times M \to \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you both. Reading now I see that a Riemann manifold is equipped with an inner product, not necessarily a metric. Would I be correct then in thinking tag the Minkowdkj metric is an inner product which is not constrained by the positive definite condition?

Comment: As I understand it (not exactly an expert here): yes, it is instead restricted by the condition that the signature of the bilinear form is $3 - 1 = 2$.

Comment: @21joanna12: A Minkowski metric is a _field_ of inner products of a particular (non-positive) signature.

Answer (score 5):

Part of the confusion in your question is due to the ambiguous use of the word "metric": it may mean either a "distance function", or a "metric tensor".

Indeed, on a Riemannian manifold the metric tensor $g$ is positive definite at every point and gives birth to a distance function $d$ by the formula

$$d(x,y) = \inf _c \int \limits _a ^b \sqrt {g(\dot c(t), \dot c(t) )} \ \Bbb d t \ ,$$

where the infimum is taken among all the differentiable curves $c$ with $c(a) = x$ and $c(b) = y$.

A Minkowskian manifold, on the other hand, is a special kind of pseudo-Riemannian (or semi-Riemannian) manifold. This time the metric tensor $g$ need not be positive at every point, anymore (all the other conditions from metric tensors on Riemannian manifolds must still be verified, though). Consequently, you can't use the same formula as above to construct a distance, because you may end up with imaginary numbers (square roots of negative numbers). In order to avoid this, you just add a modulus function under the square root, and obtain a pseudo-distance (or semi-distance):

$$d(x,y) = \inf _c \int \limits _a ^b \sqrt { |g(\dot c(t), \dot c(t) )|} \ \Bbb d t \ .$$

This $d$ has all the usual properties of a distance function, save for one: if $d(x,y) = 0$ it does no longer follow that $x=y$. This has an interesting consequence: on a Riemannian manifold, it can be proven that the topology of the manifold coincides with the topology given by the distance; this is no longer true on Hausdorff pseudo-Riemannian manifolds (the underlying topology is Hausdorff, while the topology given by the pseudo-distance can be shown no to be so).

Comment: Since any two points in Minkowski space can be connected by a piecewise linear null curve; then your "inf" definition yields d(x,y) = 0, for all x, y. The topology given by that distance function is not Hausdorff, but trivial: it's got only one open set - the whole space. The only similar ∫|√(⋯)| norm is "sup", not "inf", and only for time-like curves - as a way to define light-cone interiors (i.e. "causal sets"). The basis consists of Alexandroff intervals: intersections of past and future light cones of time-like separated points. The topology, for Minkowski geometry, is just that for ℝ⁴.

Comment: First, I do not know what "piecewise linear" means on a (Lorentzian or not) manifold. Second, are you sure that any two points in the Minkowski space may be connected by such a piecewise-linear ray of light? For instance, how would you connect the points $(t,x)$ and $(t,y)$ in $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R^3$? If two points are spacelike-separated, no (piecewise) causal curve exists between them, so I do not quite understand your comment.

Comment: It means linear everywhere, except at a finite set of points. The curve for y = |x|, for example, is piece-wise linear, with 2 linear segments. (t,x) is connected to (t,y) with two null segments that meet at (t + |x - y|/(2c), (x + y)/2). You didn't mention "causal", but only said that c(t) is differentable. No causal curves connect (t,x) with (t,y) unless x = y, so no value d((t,x),(t,y)) can be defined. For (t,x) and (u,x) with t < u, you can still connect via ((t + u)/2, x + c|t - u|/2) and that's causal. So d((t,x),(u,x)) = 0. Then, d = 0 for time-like/null, undefined for spacelike.

Comment: I meant that on a Lorentzian manifold there is no underlying linear structure, therefore "piecewise linear" does not make sense and must be replaced with something else (maybe causal piecewise geodesics?).

Comment: By "limear" I only mean that the expression c(t) is (piecewise) linear in t. Minkowski geometry does, in fact, have a linear structure separate from any prior consideration of any metric. A. A. Robb was the first to show this in 1914. He used the causal "before-after" relation as the sole primitive. Eventually it was generalized in the 1950's to show that even from the null-connectivity relation alone one can construct the entire geometry (including its linear structure!) But in any case, no matter. The d = 0 limit still follows even if you only assume the admissible curves are differentiable.

Comment: It is amusing, and frustrating at the same time, to see that you know so much yet you do not understand the elementary thing that I am trying to communicate to you: my answer is about M-A-N-I-F-O-L-D-S. Manifolds have no underlying linear structure, they are not vector spaces. They are only locally diffeomorphic to vector spaces, which is not enough to allow one to speak about (piecewise-)linear curves. This concept is meaningless on smooth *manifolds*.

Comment: #1: the original question was about Minkowski space, not manifolds in general. #2: it doesn't matter. It's still 0 even for Lorentzian manifolds. The triangle inequality is backwards for time-like curves. That's why you use "sup", not "inf". All time-like separated events on a Lorentzian manifold that can be connected by curves can be connected by null curves! And you can approximate a null curve arbitrarily closely, as a uniform limit, by causal curves. Therefore, the inf is always 0. And, as already mentioned, the "inf" is undefined for space-like separation, since "inf" is of an empty set.

Comment: Second: fix X > 0. Connect (x,t) = (0,-1) to (x,t) = (0,+1) by (x,t) = (c (cosh χ - cosh X)/sinh X, sinh χ/sinh X), for χ ∈ [-X,+X]. Then dx/dt = c tanh χ ∈ (-c, +c); so it is a causal curve. ∫√|dt² - (dx/c)²| = ∫ dχ/sinh X = 2X/sinh X. As X → ∞, 2X/sinh X → 0. Therefore, by your account, which uses "inf", d((0,-1),(0,+1)) = 0. The moral: you should be using "sup", because the triangle inequality is backwards. This is the standard way ot treating the issue. Here's a hook into the literature: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10714-022-03004-4

Comment: Third, you can always speak about curves that are piecewise linear in the curve parameter. That has absolutely nothing to do what the manifold is - and no, the concept of "piecewise linear function" is not meaningless. The function γ(t) = (c|t|, t), -1 ≤ t ≤ +1 is a piecewise linear *as a function of t*. What the underlying manifold is or is not, it irrelevant to that fact; because this talking about the the function γ(t), itself, being piecewise linear as a function t, not a manifold! That curve, in fact, is also what the uniform limit of the previously-described family of causal curves is.

Comment: And fourth, regardless of the other matters, if your answer is about "M-A-N-I-F-O-L-D-S" then it is irrelevant by that very account - because the question was *not* about manifolds, in general, but about Minkowski geometry. So, it is actually *you* who is misunderstanding what you're trying to communicate! Regardless of that fact: all of what was said about the constructibility of Minkowski geometry as a synthetic geometry using the light-connect connectivity as a sole primitive *still* generalizes to Lorentzian manifolds and *still* yields the *metric* up to conformal transform.